Computing descendants of primary operator in 2D CFT
I computed the four-point function of primaries $\partial\phi$ in the 2D free boson CFT to be $$\langle \partial\phi(z_1)\partial\phi(z_2)\partial\phi(z_3)\partial\phi(z_4) \rangle = \frac{1}{16 \pi^2} \left(\frac{1}{z_{12}^{2}z_{34}^{2}} + \frac{1}{z_{13}^{2}z_{24}^{2}} + \frac{1}{z_{14}^{2}z_{23}^{2}}\right).$$
I now want to use this result to obtain the level-two descendants of $\partial\phi$ (i.e. $[L_{-2}, \partial\phi]$ and $[L_{-1},[L_{-1}, \partial \phi]]$). I don't really know how I can adapt my previous result to obtain this. Moreover, when computing $[L_{-2}, \partial\phi]$, it doesn't seem like I can obtain a result from this. Since we can calculate $$[L_{-2}, \partial \phi(w)] = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{c_w} dz \; z^{-1} T(z) \partial \phi(w).$$ However, in the OPE expansion, we have $$T(z) \partial \phi(w)\sim \frac{\partial \phi(w)}{(z-w)^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi(w)}{(z-w)}.$$ In other words, will the $(z-w)^{-1}$ factor in the integrand of the contour integral make the regular terms in the OPE also contribute?

Francesco is right, I am wrong. It's been a while since I studied this. Apologies!

@Prahar Would you have more insight on how to compute the descendant?

That formula defines the desendant. There is nothing to compute. Do you want to find the descendant or do you want to find the correlation function of the descendant? The latter can be done.

The second part of what I want to compute asks for the computation of the 4-point correlation function of the descendant. But this I of course know how to do using $\langle L_{-2} ; \cdot \rangle = \mathscr{L}_{-2}\langle \cdot \rangle$. The question is moreso the confusion about what it means to compute the level-two descendant. So you share my opinion that there really is nothing to compute in the first place?

For the descendant obtained by hitting $\partial \phi(w)$ with $L_{-2}$, we obtain
$$[L_{-2}, \partial \phi(w)] = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{c_w} dz \; z^{-1} T(z) \partial \phi(w) = - \frac{\partial \phi(w)}{w^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi(w)}{w},$$ provided we assume $c_w$ does not contain the origin.
Similarly, we can find the other level-two descendant as $$ [L_{-1},[L_{-1}, \partial\phi(w)]] = \partial^3 \phi(w).$$

For any field $V$, the identity $\partial V = L_{-1}V$ allows you to compute correlation functions of $L_{-1}$-descendants. For correlation functions of $L_{-2}$-descendants or higher, use the local Ward identities, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4290 eq. (2.2.15).

As per my comment this is not what I'm asking...
